# Python optimisation library to use on Databricks Spark cluster

Tags: python, apache-spark, optimization, databricks, cluster-computing

I am running a Apache Spark cluster on Azure Databricks, on which I want to run an optimisation algorithm in Python. Are there any optimisation libraries built to work specifically with Spark?

I have found pymoo - but the docs specifically mention running it on a Dask cluster if distributed computing is wanted.

Comment: Hello, Have you got any solution to your problem?